# Is it possible for a program to launch Windows Search with search text already in place?

Tags: winapi, windows-11

I'm using a program which replaces the Windows 11 start menu, and it has its own built-in search functionality. I actually prefer the built-in Windows Search (after [disabling its terrible web searching feature](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/disable-windows-web-search)) and want to contribute a code change to the project which adds an option to allow launching Windows Search instead of its own search when the user starts typing, but I'm not sure if it's even possible.

Does Windows 11 have an API to do this? Not only launching Windows Search, but to do so with a character (or an entire string of characters in the event the user pasted) already populated in the search textbox, just like the official start menu does?

For reference, here's the official start menu behaving this way.

[image: 2]

Comment: The Start menu doesn't have a public API.

Comment: Whether you want to implement the Windows Search? If so, I suggest you could follow the Doc:[Windows Search as a Development Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-wds-development-ovr)